# Add a user from root with ssh key

Tags: ubuntu, shell, user-management

Perhaps a strange question, but I'm not a shell script expert.

I'm provisioning an Ubuntu server starting out as root. I'd like to non-interactively setup a new user account, remove root login and setup an ssh key, all in a single script.

What I have so far:

```
# Reconfigure sshd to disable root login
sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
# add user with no password (vagrant copies root ssh key)
useradd new-user -d /home/new-user
echo 'new-user ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
mkdir -p /home/new-user/.ssh
cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown new-user:new-user /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
# restart ssh
service ssh reload
```

This works - but I'm now a little concerned that I'm missing some kind of security loophole, or that this is a poor way of achieving the task.

Is there a simpler method for achieving this?

Thanks.

Comment: you should use `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead of `/etc/sudoers`, also `chown` should be happening on higher level (`/home/new-user/.ssh` and not just file, as otherwise `.ssh` directory will belong to root and file belong to user)

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
#!bin/sh
# $Id$

# sshd
sed -i 's/PermitRootLogin yes/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
service ssh reload

# sudo
echo '%wheel    ALL=(ALL)   ALL' > /etc/sudoers.d/wheel

# user
useradd new-user -d /home/new-user
mkdir /home/new-user/.ssh
cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /home/new-user/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R new-user:new-user /home/new-user/.ssh/
```

Comment: This code is specific for RHEL/CentOs, but is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks good enough (more experience people, please correct me!), just few caveats.

You don't need to reconfigure sshd_config for every user and it would be better to manually set up the authorized keys for the user, as every user can have different keys (but the behaviour you coded might be the one you want).

You also don't need to restart ssh after you create a user.

Comment: restart of `sshd` is needed for configuration change (`PermitRootLogin`).